# Relative dense and dense

Tags: general-topology

A set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is called relatively dense if there exists a $M>0$, s.t. every interval of length $M$ contains a $x\in A$.

I cannot find in the literature any connections to a dense subset. Is it true that any dense set is a relative dense set? The other implication is clearly not true.

Comment: See [epsilon-dense property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598522/epsilon-dense-property) AND [$\epsilon$- dense subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138620/epsilon-dense-subsets) AND [$\epsilon$-dense subsets on $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297428/epsilon-dense-subsets-on-mathbb-r-mathbb-z) AND [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delone_set).

Comment: Does this thin definition have a use?  It is hard to imagine anything dense about Z or nZ for huge n.

Comment: It actually has in the theory of almost sure periodic functions.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is dense, then, for *every* $M>0$, *every* interval with length $M$ contains an element of $A$. Therefore, $A$ is relatively dense.